# Proof by contradiction to prove that (√10)/2 is an irrational number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus, irrational-numbers

I'm struggling with a textbook question thats asks to use proof by contradiction to show that (√10)/2 is an irrational number. I tried following a similar proof that the teacher did in class, but I ended up with some random values and I'm not quite sure what I did wrong/what steps I should take next. I'm also not sure if I'm doing proof by contradiction right? Any help would be appreciated.

My attempt:

1) (√10)/2 is rational

2) (√10)/2 = a/b

3) √10 = 2a/b

4) 10 =$(2a)^2$/$b^2$

5) 10 =$4a^2$/$b^2$

6) $10b^2$=$4a^2$

7) $5b^2$=$2a^2$

Prove $a^2$ is even → a is even

1) $a^2$ is even ∧ a is odd

2) $a^2$ is even

3) a is odd

4) a = 2k + 1

5) $a^2$ = $(2k+1)^2$

6) $a^2$ = $4k^2$ + 4k + 1 = 2($2k^2$ + 2k) + 1

7) $a^2$ = 2m + 1, given m = $2k^2$ + 2k

8) $a^2$ is odd

9) $a^2$ is even ∧ $a^2$ is odd

10) false

Therefore $a^2$ → a is even

$5b^2$ = $2a^2$

a = 2c from proof above

$5b^2$ = 2$(2c)^2$

$5b^2$ = 2($4c^2$)

$5b^2$ = $8c^2$

Comment: I would go from $5b^2$ is even....

Answer (score 1):

Start with assumption that $\frac{a}{b}$ is irreducible (if it's not, we can reduce it). Thus $a$ and $b$ cannot be both even. If $a$ is even and $b$ is odd, we have a contradiction as $5b^2$ is odd and $2a^2$ is even. If $b$ is even and $a$ is odd, we can write $b=2k$. Then we have that $20k^2=2a^2 \rightarrow 10k^2=a^2$ wich is a contradiction as $a^2$ is odd, $10k^2$ is even.

The last case (thanks, Bill Dubuque) is when $a$ and $b$ are odd and do not have common factors. Then $a=2k+1$, $b=2m+1$, $5b^2=20m^2+20m+5$ is odd, $2a^2=8k^2+8k+2$ is even.

Comment: Your forgot to handle case $\,a,b\,$ both odd. Eaiser: $\,2a^2 = 5b^2$ is even so $b$ is even, so $\,5b(b/2) = a^2 $ is even so $a$ is even, contra $\,a,b\,$ coprime.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Appreciate your comment, I missed this case.